# When should I transfer my Fiddle Leaf Fig to a bigger pot?

Tags: trees, houseplants, transplanting, container-gardening, ficus

My [Fiddle Leaf Fig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_lyrata) tree is getting taller. I was wondering if I should change the pot to a bigger pot? I took the picture of my plant next to a standard cereal box so you can have an idea of how tall it is. Unfortunately, I don't have anything to measure it with.

[image: fig]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main reasons for re-potting are that the soil is depleted of nutrients or the plant has out grown the size of the pot. Check the underside of the pot for roots coming through. This indicates the plant has reached the limit of the pot size.  If there are none, inspect the quality of the soil to see if it perhaps need a feed or if all the smaller, finer grains are gone and only larger clumps or pieces of bark/mulch matter are left. This would indicate that the soil needs replacing (which can be done and then place the plant back in the same pot).
Hope this helps!